# How is the derivative of a potential with respect to an outward normal equal to the grad of the potential

Tags: surface-integrals

If we first consider Gauss' Law
$$\oint_s \boldsymbol{E\cdot} \,d\boldsymbol{A} = Q_{enclosed\\in\ surface}$$
We know from physics that $\boldsymbol{E}=-\nabla V$, but I want to know is it mathematically equivalent to say $-\partial V/\partial n = \nabla V$ -- and if so, how? Here, $n$ is the outward normal from the enclosed surface.

Comment: $\frac{\partial V}{\partial n}$ is a scalar, while $\nabla V$ is a vector.  The correct relationship is $\frac{\partial V}{\partial n} = \nabla V \cdot n$, where $\cdot$ denotes the dot-product.

Comment: @Omnomnomnom is that then saying that $n$ is really a unit vector/versor?

Comment: Yes, $n$ is the unit vector which points outward from the enclosed surface

Comment: @Omnomnomnom but surely in this case $\boldsymbol{E}$ is my normal vector? Because, $\boldsymbol{E} = \nabla V = (\partial _{x}V,\partial _{y}V,\partial _{z}V)$

Comment: What makes you think that the direction of $E$ is necessarily normal to the surface?

Comment: @Omnomnomnom Nothing, which is the reason for my confusion. See http://mathworld.wolfram.com/NormalVector.html -- Specifically Eq. (3)

Comment: Right, so the point is that $E$ is **not** your normal vector.

Comment: In that context, the function $f$ is used to describe the surface.  There is no connection between $\nabla f$ as it's used in that context and our $\nabla V$, the vector field to be integrated.

Comment: @Omnomnomnom RIGHT. Yes you are correct. I was just pattern matching and not thinking there -- thanks!